# Jackson XML Mapper Writing Element name twice for lists

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson

I have a class `Submission` (shown below) which has a list called return
of type Return. When I deserialize the object the `Return` element twice.
Is there a way for the return element to only occur once?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ReturnType", propOrder = {
    "t619",
    "_return"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Submission")
public class Submission {

    @XmlElement(name = "Return", required = true)
    protected List<Return> _return;
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ReturnChoiceType", propOrder = {
    "t4",
    "t4A",
    ...
})
public class Return {

    @XmlElement(name = "T4")
    protected T4ReturnType t4;

    ...
}
```

Generated XML

```
<Return> <!-- One return -->
    <Return> <!-- Another return -->
      <T4>
      </T4>
    </Return>
</Return>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, `Return` element contains `List` of `Return` object.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Return", required = true)
    protected List<Return> _return;
```

You need to change `List<Return>` to `List<String>`

```
 protected List<String> _return;
```

As you haven't shared complete details of `Return` class, but I'm assuming you may need to change something there as well.